# Angular-6 Keyboard hides auotmatically when user click on input field

Tags: html, angular, input, keyboard

When the app is run on a mobile phone, we sometimes have issues that the keyboard popup's and directly hides again. The user click on input field in order to write something, keyboards hide

This occurs on Samsung Galaxy A32 & Samsung Galaxy A31

I am stuck and can't proceed. Please suggest me a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The soft keyboard on device OS typically auto hides when the `input` field which triggered the keyboard pop up suddenly gets `blur` - meaning you've lost focus on the input and thus the keyboard will go away. Try to find the reason why you lose focus or blur out when you start typing. Or give use some relevant code to debug.

Comment: <div fxFlex="100%" style="text-align: -webkit-center !important;" *ngIf="!oldApp">
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 270px; height: 50px; margin-top: 3%;" name="emailAddress"
                  placeholder="Email Address" [(ngModel)]="EmailAddress" maxlength="100" [required]="true"
                  [disabled]="OtpVerified || OtpGenerated" (ngModelChange)="onEmailChange($event)" type="email"
                  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : EmailAddress&&!EmailAddressValid}" />
              </div>

Comment: I'm using above line of code. See if helpful

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Please refactor your previous answer and the next comment into your main post and format the code in a readable way.  For not it could be any one of those methods causing it. Or outdated libraries with some bugs which cause inconsistent behaviour.